# Spring inner class with YAML property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, javabeans

I have a Spring component that has an inner class. All the members are loaded from a YAML file.

When this component is used in another configuration I see the inner class is not initialized.

The code is

```java
@Component
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "company")
public class Company {
  @JsonProperty("connectTimeout")
  private Integer connectTimeout;
  @JsonProperty("dept1")
  private Department library;
  @JsonProperty("dept2")
  private Department admin;

    //Getters and Setters


  @SuppressWarnings({"PublicInnerClass", "WeakerAccess"})
  public static class Department {
      @JsonProperty("connectTimeout")
      private Integer connectTimeout;
  //Getters and Setters
  }
}
```

When the component Company is used in another Configuration during the startup I see the `connectTimeout` is loading up fine as 1000, but the `library` and `admin` are shown as null.

The YAML file is like below

```
company:
  connectTimeout: 1000
  dept1:
    connectTimeout: 100
  dept2:
    connectTimeout: 100
```

Comment: are these properties loaded from "application.yml"?

Comment: I don't see `admin` and `library` in yml, are they from same yml?